# jquery trigger or click not working?

Tags: jquery, triggers, click

I am really struggling why I can't get this trigger or click to work?

here is the JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {     

    function libertyPop(){  
        var popUp = jQuery("#lightbox-30835684809970");
        popUp.click();
        popUp.trigger('click');
        console.log("should work");
    }

    libertyPop();
});
```

This should be triggering a click on this anchor:

```
<a id="lightbox-30835684809970" style="cursor:pointer;color:blue;text-decoration:underline;">
    Liberty Pop-Up
</a>
```

In the page, when I actually click on the link, the pop up will appear, i don't understand why the jquery 'trigger' or 'click' is not doing the same?

Comment: Are you triggering the click handler before you've attached it?

Comment: BTW, your code is quite ugly here. Why set the click handler inside a function?

Comment: No, i do have the anchor in my html, and load the JS after

Comment: @Xtian so what is supposed to do the click on anchor? With the code you provide, it'll do nothing

Comment: Presumably you have a lightbox plugin, and at some point you're initialising the plugin on your element. If you're triggering the click handler **before** initialising the plugin on that element, it won't do anything

Comment: I just need the anchor tag to be 'clicked' for the pop-up to appear, this is how it was suggested i do it from the 3rd Party who made the Pop-Up

Comment: You can just trigger the click immediately after initialising it, something like: `$('#lightbox-xxx').lightbox().click()` providing the plugin returns the element to support chaining

Comment: Are you sure the element will always have the same ID: `lightbox-30835684809970`  looks like using a timestamp for me

Comment: I really think you need to adjust this question to account for the fact you are trying to get a lightbox plugin to work. Be explicit about which one and how you are instantiating it.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to trigger native click event of anchor tag, use js event:

```
 var popUp = jQuery("#lightbox-30835684809970")[0]; //<< [0] will retruns the DOM node

  popUp.click();
```

But as you didn't have setted attribute href, this will do nothing!

If you want to trigger click handler attached using jQuery, first set one.

Using your code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {     

    function libertyPop(){  
        var popUp = jQuery("#lightbox-30835684809970");
        popUp.on('click',function(){
            console.log("WORKS!");
        }).click();
    }

    libertyPop();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You're not actually adding an event handler before triggering the event. It has nothing to do...

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#lightbox-30835684809970").click(function(){

        console.log('clicked');

    });

    $("#lightbox-30835684809970").trigger('click');

});
```

Here's a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LM8Pd/)

Comment: I have tried this as well, but it is not actually triggering a click.  If i manually click on the link, the pop-up works.  But for using either of these doesn't seem to do anything. I can't figure out why

Comment: which lightbox plugin are you using?

Comment: @Xtian i'm quite sure element use timestamp ID, check your DOM. In this case, find an other selector than ID, e.g class or transversal selector